# atom: hydrogen installed, but the code is not running (on macOS)

Tags: python, macos, kernel, atom-editor, hydrogen

I have  the following setting:

- `Python 3.7.2`
- `macOS 10.14`
- `Atome 1.35.1`
- `Script 3.18.1`
- `Hydrogen 2.8.0`

running code works in `Terminal` as well as in atom with `script` but nothing happen when running the code with hydrogen:

[image: hydrogen output]

In the `Language Mappings` of `Hydrogen` it is written:

`{ "python": "magicpython", "python3": "magicpython" }`

when running `jupyter kernelspec list`
I get: `python3      /usr/local/etc/jupyter/kernels/python3`. In this directory there is a `kernel.json` file with the following content:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/bin",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
"env": {
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.3.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/7.3.0/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages"
}
,
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

in the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/bin` there are the following items

```
2to3            pip3.7          python3.7-config
2to3-3.7        pydoc3          python3.7m
easy_install-3.7    pydoc3.7        python3.7m-config
idle3           python3         pyvenv
idle3.7         python3-config      pyvenv-3.7
pip3            python3.7       wheel3
```

Is the path in the kernel.json file the correct one?

I also looked at this [github page](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1432) but I couldn't solve the problem

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your kernelspec argv argument is pointing to `../python.3x/bin` instead of directly to the `python3` executable. Pointing to the executable directly with `../python.3x/bin/python3` is more typical and might be the issue.

How did you install your kernel? I'd recommend taking a look at [this kernel installation guide](https://nteract.io/kernels/python) and probably reinstalling your kernel with, in your case, `python3 -m ipykernel install`. I think this will work, but, manually editing the kernel.json file would be another (not recommended) way to fix this.

Comment: many thanks @BenRussert. So I did both things (ran `python3 -m ipykernel` and changed the path in the .json file). I don't know what worked but it worked